# How to make a border line

Tags: c#, border

So I am making a game and I am trying to make a borderline that goes from the top of the console to the bottom of the console on the left side of my console. This is my code for trying to make the line

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.WindowWidth + 20);
Console.Write(new string( '|', Console.WindowHeight));
```

My size for this console is

```
Console.SetWindowSize(120, 30);
Console.SetBufferSize(120, 30);
```

I am just a beginner so if there is a simple way to do it can someone help me please.

Comment: The `[visual-studio]` tag should only be used for questions about the Visual Studio _application_.

Comment: Does your code work? Does it fall short somehow? We need to know exactly how your current situation differs from your desired outcome. See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my code, I have found most of the code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=netframework-4.8) and adapted it to your needs.

```
protected static int origRow;
protected static int origCol;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.SetWindowSize(120, 30);

    // Clear the screen, then save the top and left coordinates.
    Console.Clear();
    origRow = Console.CursorTop;
    origCol = Console.CursorLeft;

    int height = Console.WindowHeight;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        WriteAt("|", 0, i);

    // this is to force to keep the application running. Now visual studio
    // will not put some extra text at the end of the screen
    Console.ReadLine();
}

// write a string as location x,y
public static void WriteAt(string s, int x, int y)
{
    try
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(origCol + x, origRow + y);
        Console.Write(s);
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```